# Alter nth child on hover of another nth child, CSS only

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an unordered list that I've styled into a table to try and add some order to a list that I can't change any other way (don't have access).

When you hover over one of the `<li>`, I want the corresponding `<li>` at the top of the column to highlight yellow.

It's only the first 32 children in the `<li>` that are affected so I have this:

```
#list_1 li:nth-child(-n+32):hover + #list_1 li:nth-child(-n+(n-1)) {
    background:yellow;
}
```

But this obviously doesn't work. I can only find solutions using js but I can't use this or affect any of the markup as it's not mine so it needs to be done in the CSS.

Any ideas?

Comment: We really need to see the column arrangement and CSS -  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Without a previous sibling selector this is tricky. Just to clarify, is there actually more than 32 children in the list, but you only want the hover to affect the first 32?